# PHP not storing query result

Tags: php, mysql

For a particular query

```
SELECT MAX(theCount), day 
    FROM (SELECT FK_Hour, day As day, Count(FK_Hour) As theCount 
        FROM (Select slottime.FK_Hour, time.day 
            From slottime INNER JOIN time ON slottime.FK_Hour = time.Hour ) 
            As C GROUP By FK_Hour 
        ) 
        AS counts GROUP By day
```

The database returns
[image: phpmyadmin]

However when running the php code

```
$timequery = array();    
try {
       $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(theCount), day 
                            FROM (SELECT FK_Hour, day As day, Count(FK_Hour) As theCount 
                                FROM (Select slottime.FK_Hour, time.day 
                                    From slottime INNER JOIN time ON slottime.FK_Hour = time.Hour ) 
                                    As C GROUP By FK_Hour 
                                ) 
                                AS counts GROUP By day 
                            ");
   $sth->execute();


   while ($timequery = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $timequery[] = $results;
   }
   echo("trying  ");
   print_r($timequery);
   echo("  tried");
}
```

The output is merely

> trying tried

Comment: where is $results? its initialized?

Comment: @UnniBabu. Thank you. Code should be while ($results = $sth -> fetch [...]) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$results seem to be uninitialized... Change code as shown below

```
while ($results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```